Testcontainers, getting error while pulling image testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.4
I am working on testcontainers with spring boot. Until last week, it was working fine and all of a sudden i started getting below error when running test cases. It seems when test container try to download ryuk:0.3.4 image, it gets time out error. Not sure why it started happening which was working fine.
error pulling image configuration: Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/04/0449114d1f768ef3d5df4e0067daecb26b3183059e74d270d03a8f90a8c72ce3/data?verify=1718805954-lZfUlhMrV0M3NNCEHNhW1jRYe74%3D: dial tcp 31.13.85.169:443: i/o timeout

even when i try to pull the image manually also, i am getting the same error
docker pull testcontainers/ryuk:0.3.4

